# How to add method name to sleuth spans?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin, jaeger

im using

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

and jaeger to collect and show spans
[image]

on screenshot only info `myapp-app: get be4eed3` but it makes hard to investigate and find some particular method.

How to customize it to
${method name in controller}
and add some additional info ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Inject a SpanHandler bean and change the span name to the controller method name:

```
        @Bean
        SpanHandler spanHandler() {
            return new SpanHandler() {
                @Override
                public boolean end(TraceContext traceContext, MutableSpan span, Cause cause) {
                    String operation = span.tags().getOrDefault("mvc.controller.method", null);
                    if(operation != null) {
                        span.name(operation);
                    }
    
                   
                    return true;
          }
      }
```

Comment: yes it works
```
 @Override
            public boolean end(TraceContext traceContext, MutableSpan span, Cause cause) {
                Map<String, String> tags = span.tags();
                if(tags.get("http.path") != null){
                    span.name(tags.get("http.method") + " " + tags.get("http.path"));
                }

                return true;
            }
        };
```